# Not able to get indian standard time in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

using this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

is returning a wrong time result. If the real date time is `2015-10-02 12:00:00` it's showing `2015-10-03 12:30:00`. How can I get the right 'ist'?

Answer (score 0):

It's giving you a UTC time , while Indian Timezone is UTC + 5.30. So you have to set your timezone to Asia/Calcutta in your root index file.

```
<?php
$indiatimezone = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata" );
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone($indiatimezone);
echo  $date->format( 'H:i:s A  /  D, M jS, Y' );
?>
```

Comment: did you try this http://tutorialsplane.com/how-to-get-current-date-time-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

With CodeIgniter, the best place to set the timezone is inside the main `index.php` file.  It's at the same level in your project structure as the `system/` and `application/` folders.

Just add the following as the first line of code in the file after the opening `<?php` tag:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

The timezone for the database will probably be different as well.  If you're using MySQL, you'll want to do a `SET time_zone = "+05:30"` query as soon as you open a database connection.

Comment: how is that different from the question?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

**Option One**

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$t=time();
echo($t . "<br>");
echo(date("Y-m-d h:i:s",$t));
```

**Option Two** (***Codeigniter method***)

```
$this->load->helper('date');
echo timezones('UP45');//for India UP45
$now = time();
echo unix_to_human($now); // no seconds
```

Comment: how is that any different from the question?

Comment: i cant find this `echo now();` and `$datetime1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));` in his question. So how this lines come true ***your are basically posting the exact same code as the question***

Comment: note, it is very much possible that op has no clue and leaves out a lot of details. It's just that I was reviewing your answer and it very much appear that the real answer to his question is: we can't answer because the problem is not in the code you [the op] posted ;-)